# In an Azure Function, how do I access the information logged to the console from within the code

Tags: azure, function, logging

I have an Azure Function that runs every half hour. I have set the log configuration to redirect to the console.

```
    Configuration.Default.Logger.Level = 
    PureCloudPlatform.Client.V2.Client.LogLevel.LTrace;
    Configuration.Default.Logger.Format = LogFormat.JSON;
    Configuration.Default.Logger.LogRequestBody = true;
    Configuration.Default.Logger.LogResponseBody = true;
    Configuration.Default.Logger.LogToConsole = true;
    Configuration.Default.Logger.LogFilePath = tempFolder+"\\dotnetsdk.log";
```

I can see in the console that "Inin-Correlation-Id" is being logged. However, I cannot  get access to this from within the code. I redirect the output to a log file but I cannot read this log file from the code as it is always in use.

How do I get access to the information logged to the console from within the code?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. But can you clarify what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the logged information in the console from can be accessed within the code.

For this you need to do the below things.

1. In `Host.Json` file you need to mention "fileLoggingMode": "always".

[image]

2. Need to take the log file from the path using RUN command as below. "%temp%\LogFiles\Application\Functions".

[image]

3. Read the log file from the path and use the logs or text in your code by using the below code.

[image]

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            string folder_Path = @"C:\Users\V-NMOP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\LogFiles\Application\Functions\Host";
            string[] Myfiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder_Path);
            string recent_File = Myfiles.OrderByDescending(f => new FileInfo(f).LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault();
            string txt = File.ReadAllText(recent_File);

            return new OkObjectResult(txt);
        }
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I create a new logger class

```
using System.IO;

public class ConsoleToFileLogger : TextWriter
{
    private readonly TextWriter _consoleWriter;
    private readonly string _logFilePath;

    public ConsoleToFileLogger(string logFilePath)
    {
        _consoleWriter = Console.Out;
        _logFilePath = logFilePath;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        _consoleWriter.Write(value); // Write to the console

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(_logFilePath, true))
        {
            writer.Write(value); // Write to the file
        }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _consoleWriter.Flush();
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding => _consoleWriter.Encoding;
}
```

and then in the function code

```
 var logFilePath = "<path_to_log_file>";

        // Create an instance of the custom logger
        var consoleToFileLogger = new ConsoleToFileLogger(logFilePath);

        // Redirect the console output to the file
        Console.SetOut(consoleToFileLogger);

       

        // Make sure to flush and close the logger when you're done
        consoleToFileLogger.Flush();
        consoleToFileLogger.Close();
```